# is a loop a path in graphs. If yes then what is the length of this path

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $a\in V$ with $(a,a)\in E.$ Then, is $(a,a)$ a path from $a$ to $a.$ If yes then what is the length of this path.

Answer (score 3):

Your question itself, assuming more or less standard definitions, implies several "facts" of which I am not sure you really intend to imply them.

Your statement that $(a,a)\in E$ suggests (implicitly) that you are allowing loops: otherwise $(a,a)$ can never be in $E$.

The fact that you specify the path as $(a,a)$ suggests that you are not allowing multiple edges: if you allow multiple edges a path cannot be specified by vertices alone, you also have to specify the edges taken.

In the absence of a length function on the edges (and you did not mention one) the length of each edge is taken to be 1.

The standard definition of a path does not allow vertex repetition, so according to this definition $(a,a)$ would not be a path. However sometimes other definitions are used. If your definition of a path does allow vertex repetition $(a,a)$ is a path and its length is 1.

Comment: Good answer. Assuming standard definitions, a loop is not a path, but it is a cycle of length 1, right?

Comment: Yes (filling up until minimum length of comment)